# Wordpress pluginfile is showing inactive even when my plugin is active and no chnages in any file taking any effect

Tags: wordpress

Hi I have installed one plugin on my wordpress blog And tried to edit a particular file. but my edits are not showing any effect. Possibly due to file showing inactive. Can someone help me in activating the file for a plugin(in this case All in one seo plugin).

Attaching screenshot of how the file is showing inactive.

[image]

Any help/suggestion will be appriciated a lot.